# how to Write code that reads the selected item form the ListBox

Tags: c#

Below is a question tell me whether the solution i provided is correct or what is the correct solution.

Question: Assume nameListBox is ListBox control. Write code that reads the selected item form the ListBox. Be sure to prevent an exception from occurring in case no item has been selected.

MY CODE:

```
nameListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

if (nameListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
Messagebox.show(“now item has been seleced”)
}
```

Comment: `if (nameListBox.SelectedIndex == -1) { MessageBox.Show("no item has been seleced"); } else { MessageBox.Show(nameListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()); }`?

Comment: The code works as per your logic?

Comment: nah not really unfortunately

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed is that the correct solution?

Comment: What output do you expect? What actual output do you get?

Comment: This is just like theory mid sem question. we don't use a computer to do the test but we get questions like this so we don't test it, IK its weird, but thats how it is.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what will happen if nothing is selected. You can handle this two ways.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no item has been seleced");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Or use directly try catch to handle exception

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i do that